# Rxjs6 from rxjs5: Handling Observables in REST API method

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I am brand-spanking new to rxjs and Angular, and I've just discovered (thanks to my WebStorm giving me tons of red error messages) that rxjs5 is way different from version 6.

So I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-rxjs-create-api-service-rest-backend/), which guides users through assembling the API service with rxjs. The problem is, it's written for version 5.

Here is a sample API route written in **version 5**:

```
public getAllTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
  return this.http
   .get(API_URL + '/todos')
   .map(response => {
     const todos = response.json();
     return todos.map((todo) => new Todo(todo));
   })
   .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

After reading the documentation, I've gotten the **version 6** route re-written to this point:

```
public getAllTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
  return this.http
   .get(API_URL + '/todos')
   .pipe(
     map(response => {
      return response.map((todo) => new Todo(todo));
     }),
     catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.

I am guessing this has to do with the response not being in json format, although the response does not seem to have a .json() method.

Comment: `pipe ( tap(v => console.log(v)))` is your friend. Check whatever is your observable at that stage and adapt the code accordingly.

Comment: For angular the idiomatic way (using HttpClient) is `return this.http.get<Todo[]>(url).pipe( map( res => res.map(todo => new Todo(todo)), catchError(handleErr)  );`  - notice the generic  `get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you have an error is that if you don't specify the type of your `response` variable, it is assumed to be an Object. As `map` is an array function, you need to specify the type of your response to be an array:

```
this.http.get<any[]>(...).pipe(...); // Preferred
```

or:

```
this.http.get(...).pipe(map((response: any[]) => ...)...);
```

Note that you should replace `any` in the above with the actual type that is being returned from your API (string, object, etc.).